# Retrieving data according to a set of categories

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve a set of restaurant menu data grouping them according to menu category and create list of menu items for each menu category and create a HashMap of these lists with  a key of category.

The below JSON tree displays how I'm storing the menu items for each restaurant under a restaurant ID.

```
  "Menu" : { 
    "C39Jv1oVVdXbQdyCOcTQZyZnmC3x" : {  //Restaurant ID
      "applepie" : {
        "item_category" : "Desserts",
        "item_name" : "Apple Pie",
        "item_price" : "280"
      },
      "chocopudding" : {
        "item_category" : "Desserts",
        "item_name" : "Chocolate Pudding",
        "item_price" : "320"
      },
      "friedrice" : {
        "item_category" : "Main Courses",
        "item_name" : "Fried Rice",
        "item_price" : "250"
      },
      "seafoodrice" : {
        "item_category" : "Main Courses",
        "item_name" : "Sea Food Fried Rice",
        "item_price" : "300"
      }
    }
  }
```

The categories of food each restaurant is stored in `MenuCategories` node

```
"MenuCategories" : {
    "C39Jv1oVVdXbQdyCOcTQZyZnmC3x" : { //Restaurant ID
      "Desserts " : true,
      "Main Courses" : true
    }
  }
```

What I'm trying to achieve according to the above data-set is something like :

1. List1 :(menu,menu) //Desserts
2. List2 :(menu,menu) //Main Courses

Here's my attempt (minus the part of creating lists and Hashmap to keep the code short):

Database references for both nodes:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Menu").child(res_id);
mMenuCategoryRef  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MenuCategories").child(res_id);
```

Data retrieval :

```
List<String> menuCatList  = new ArrayList<>();
mMenuCategoryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

   for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

       menuCatList.add(data.getKey()); //adds all the categories to array list

   }

   for(String menuCat : menuCatList){

   //I'm trying to retrieve items under each category                   
       mDatabase.orderByChild("item_category").equalTo(menuCat).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                   System.out.println("MenuListWithCat "+data.getKey()+" - "+data.getValue());
               }

           }
              .....
```

According to my code, I'm only receiving items with category "Main Courses", this is what my println prints.

```
 `System.out.println("MenuListWithCat "+data.getKey()+" - "+data.getValue());`

    MenuListWithCat friedrice - {item_name=Fried Rice, item_category=Main Courses, item_price=250}
    MenuListWithCat seafoodrice - {item_name=Sea Food Fried Rice, item_category=Main Courses, item_price=300}
```

It completely skips over "Desserts" category, why is that?

Any assistance regarding this would be very helpful.

Comment: If you put a log statement in `onDataChange` for `mMenuCategoryRef`, does it print? In other words: is it failing to retrieve the categories themselves? Or is it failing in the inner loop to retrieve the menu items for those categories.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, both category types are retrieved and added to the `menuCatList`. Maybe the structure that I'm using to store the menu items under the Menu node is not suitable, any thoughts?

Comment: Well.... your data structure certainly looks somewhat unusual. Since you already have the item categories for each restaurant under `/Menu/$restaurantId`, I don't really see why you need a `/MenuCategories/$restaurantId`. But the code seems fine, so I'm not sure why it isn't reading the menu items in the inner loop. Maybe someone else spots what's wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes I agree, I was able to sort it out. Please check my answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I was complicating my Firebase data retrieval process in order to make separate lists of menu items for each category, I decided to retrieve all menu items and add it to an ArrayList without considering their category types, like below:

```
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

         Menu menu = child.getValue(Menu.class);
         menuList.add(menu);

     }
```

And then group all menu items according to their category and added them to separate lists using a bit of Java logic, which gives me a HashMap of the following format:

```
Map<ItemCategory, ListofItems>
```

Here's the logic:

```
Map<String, List<Menu>> menuMap= new HashMap<String, List<Menu>>();

    for(Menu menuItem : menuList){

        List<Menu> tempList = menuMap.get(menuItem.getItem_category());

        if(tempList == null){

            tempList = new ArrayList<Menu>();
            menuMap.put(menuItem.getItem_category(), tempList);

        }

        tempList.add(menuItem);
    }
```

And I removed the `MenuCategories` node from the database which was not needed, as Frank mentioned in the comments.

I hope this would help someone in the future! :)

Special thanks @Frank for valuable feedback and support.